# An error has occurred See the log file /Users/georgethornton/workspace/.metadata/.log

Tags: java, eclipse

Now, I hope this isn't a duplicate question, as its title is similar to the question at this link: An error has ocurred. See the log file /User/workspace/.metadata/.log [duplicate] . But it shouldn't be because I have Eclipse IDE downloaded already. For convenience, my version of Eclipse is Neon 3 and I use it on my Apple MacBook Air.

**The Error** 
When I click on the icon, on my Desktop to open the Eclipse IDE, a few seconds later, I get the 'An error has occurred.' dialog box. The message is

> See the log file /Users/georgethornton/workspace/.metadata/.log.

Now, I had a look in my workspace directory, as the directory hierarchy suggested. However, it doesn't contain any files or sub-directories in it yet, as I haven't had Eclipse on my Laptop for that long. What am I gonna do to get the .metadata and .log files that I need? for right now, I am lost as to what to do !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look and see if any information has been left in your System log (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6479662).

For information, the .metadata folder will be hidden, if you haven't already known this, to view hidden folders hold CMD+SHIFT+FULLSTOP.